# Authentication / PrincipalPermission not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication, principal

I work in WCF and am writing my Authentication Manager which is based on `IHttpModule` and it works fine. One the of methods in my `Authentication` class creates a `GenericPrincipal` object in `Context.User`.

For example

```
app.Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("Scott"), new string[] { "read" });
```

In one of methods in `Service` I want to assign the user `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` and I don't how it should work, but it always throws a `SecurityException`. For example:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="read")]  // it throw SecurityException
    public SampleItem GetCollection()
    {
        bool user = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("read"); // return true
        bool user1 = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("write"); // return false

        return SampleItem.GetSampleItem();
    }
```

Maybe `PrincipalPremissionAttribute` doesn't use `Context.Current.User`? But if not then what?

I tried remove the problem, and made a very simple attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple=true, Inherited=false)]
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAuthorizationAttribute(params string[]  roles)
    {
        foreach (string item in roles)
        {
            if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(item) == false)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic Realm");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = "Access Denied";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("401 Access Denied");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the application can't use this. What I mean is, when I set a breakpoint on the `MyAttribute` constructor, the compiler doesn't stop on the beakpoint, it doesn't see it.

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    [MyAuthorization("read")]
    public SampleItem GetCollection()
    {
        bool user = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("read"); // return true
        bool user1 = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("write"); // return false

        return SampleItem.GetSampleItem();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using AspNetCompatibility?

Comment: Yes i use AspNetCompatibility. It's standard write in web.config becouse i use WCF REST 40 template

Answer (score 3):

With WCF you need to associate custom principals via a [very specific mechanism](http://www.leastprivilege.com/CustomPrincipalsAndWCF.aspx), which works fine. Note also that attributes *generally* **do not** cause code execution, and only get invoked when done explicitly done via reflection (unless you are using PostSharp). You can't just add an attribute and have it do things automatically. MVC etc gives that *impression*, but there is code in MVC checking for attributes and executing them manually.

Comment: @Martin I think this is the same content: https://www.google.com/amp/s/leastprivilege.com/2007/08/08/custom-principals-and-wcf/amp/